# Improving performance of headless Selenium

Tags: python, ubuntu, selenium

I'm running [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) on a headless Ubuntu server using Xvfb as outlined [here](http://www.alittlemadness.com/2008/03/05/running-selenium-headless/).

I'm launching Xvfb with:

```
#!/bin/bash
disp=${1:-"99"}
/usr/bin/Xvfb :$disp -ac 2>&1 | tee /var/log/run-xvfb.log
```

And I'm launching Selenium-Server with:

```
#!/bin/bash
disp=${1:-"0"}
export DISPLAY=":$disp" && java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.21.0.jar 2>&1 | tee /var/log/run-selenium-server.log
```

My startup code looks like:

```
from selenium import selenium
sel = selenium('localhost', 4444, '*firefox', 'http://www.google.com')
sel.start() # This takes forever!!!
<do stuff>
```

I'm finding it usually works, but the `sel.start()` can take 15 minutes or more to complete. Oddly, the log files are never written so I don't know if any errors are occurring. It just seems to be "hanging".

When I run this same code on my local machine, which is also Ubuntu but has a normal desktop GUI setup, it takes less than a minute, so I know something is going horribly wrong on the server. How can I diagnose what's wrong, and improve Selenium's horrible performance?

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not contain enough details to give you a good answer but I can give you some tips that might help. Without logs this is an incredible hard problem to debug.

By default Selenium tries to emulate a real user as close as possible. This means that it will wait until pages are fully loaded before doing anything on them. A slow third-party script can cause long hangups.

If found that by default the Selenium BaseTest(unittest.TestCase) also contained this line:

```
self.driver.implicitly_wait(20)
```

Removing this line should speedup every test quite a bit. This line could be ignored by your normal Selenium setup (because it uses a different initialization).

For further speedups I recommend you take a look at PhantomJS. Even with optimization the Firefox test is going to take a few minutes.